# how to solve this joining of tables?

Tags: php, mysql

I want to join the two tables transaction and item but some rows are returning with null values but in the database they have values. I need this query in the  php I'm working with. the tables and query is below. . please help me. .

```html
mysql> select * from item;
+----------+-------------------------+-----+--------+
| itemcode | item_abb                | qty | price  |
+----------+-------------------------+-----+--------+
| 02901    | King Bed                |  34 | 150000 |
| 26350    | King Size Dinning Table |  33 | 15000  |
| 33321    | Sofa                    |  30 | 4500   |
| 4526     | chandelier              |  22 | 5000   |
+----------+-------------------------+-----+--------+
4 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from transaction;
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| datetime            | transtype | itemcode | prevstock | qty1 | currentstock |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
| 2017-04-08 20:49:37 | stockin   | 4526     |        11 |   12 |           23 |
| 2017-04-08 20:50:35 | stockout  | 2901     |        40 |    2 |           38 |
| 2017-04-08 21:00:35 | stockout  | 4526     |        23 |    1 |           22 |
| 2017-04-08 22:24:16 | stockout  | 2901     |        38 |    2 |           36 |
| 2017-04-09 06:41:47 | stockout  | 2901     |        36 |    2 |           34 |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)

mysql> select * from transaction left join item on transaction.itemcode = item.itemcode;
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+----------+------------+------+-------+
| datetime            | transtype | itemcode | prevstock | qty1 | currentstock | itemcode | item_abb   | qty  | price |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+----------+------------+------+-------+
| 2017-04-08 20:49:37 | stockin   | 4526     |        11 |   12 |           23 | 4526     | chandelier |   22 | 5000  |
| 2017-04-08 20:50:35 | stockout  | 2901     |        40 |    2 |           38 | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | NULL  |
| 2017-04-08 21:00:35 | stockout  | 4526     |        23 |    1 |           22 | 4526     | chandelier |   22 | 5000  |
| 2017-04-08 22:24:16 | stockout  | 2901     |        38 |    2 |           36 | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | NULL  |
| 2017-04-09 06:41:47 | stockout  | 2901     |        36 |    2 |           34 | NULL     | NULL       | NULL | NULL  |
+---------------------+-----------+----------+-----------+------+--------------+----------+------------+------+-------+
5 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

Comment: There is not `2901` in your `item` table, so it will return `NULL` as you are doing a `LEFT JOIN`. If you don't want to return rows will `NULL` values you need to do a `JOIN`

Comment: You used `left join`, so even if there is no item with matching itemcode, transaction will be returned. And you clearly don't have item with itemcode `2901`. You can use `join` instead to return only transaction with related items if that's what you want.

Comment: I did not notice the the item code. . . thank you . . the problem is solved :D

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Your question is well formatted and looks nice, unlike some other new users. +1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you use a left join all rows from the table on the left side of the join are returned.  It looks like you were intending to use an inner join where only rows where both tables have the join condition exist.

`select * from transaction join item on transaction.itemcode = item.itemcode;`